# A problem on holomorphic functions in open unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ be non-constant holomorphic function in unit disc $\{|z|<1\}$ such that $f(0)=1$. Then prove that it is necessary that there are infinitely many points $z$ in the unit disc such that $|f(z)|=1$.

Please help me out with the question..

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What theorems come to mind that may be useful here?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 - that potential duplicate has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to these sorts of problems is to use the maximum modulus principle. Suppose by way of contradiction, that $|f(z)|=1$ for only finitely many points inside the disc.

That means there is a $\delta$ for which $|f(z)| < 1$ (you can handle the case $|f(z)|>1$ separately) for all $z \in B_{\delta}(0) \setminus \{0\}$. However, this means that $|f(0)| = 1$ is larger than $|f(\delta e^{i\theta})|$ for all $\theta$. Hence $f(z)$ is constant in $B_{\delta}(0)$, and hence $f$ is constant on $B_1(0)$. This is a contradiction.

I left some details in here up to you. But that is the general idea.