# non constant holomorphic functiom

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is a non-constant holomorphic function in the unit disc $|z|<1$ that satisfies $f(0)=1$ , then prove that there are infinitely many points $z$ lying inside the disc such that $|f(z)|=1$. How can one prove this result?

Comment: Note that an open neighborhood of $0$ will be mapped to an open neighborhood of $1 = f(0)$ (open mapping theorem)

Comment: yes by open mapping theorem.

Comment: then how infinitely many points will come such that |f(z)|=1.

Comment: Consider the intersection of the unit circle $\{|z|=1\}$ with that neighborhood around 1. It contains infinitely many points.

Comment: yes exaclty it will contains infinitely many points of the circle...

Comment: thanking you nicely explained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A problem on holomorphic functions in open unit disk](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933989/a-problem-on-holomorphic-functions-in-open-unit-disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m_r = \inf_{|z|= r} |f(z)|$, $M_r = \sup_{|z|= r} |f(z)|$.

Since $f$ is not constant, for $r \in (0,1)$, we have $M_r>1, m_r <1$ (this follows from the open mapping theorem and the maximum/minimum modulus theorem). The intermediate value theorem shows that for each $r \in (0,1)$ there is some $z_r$ with $|z_r| = r$ such that $|f(z_r)| = 1$.